# less2css Sublime Text path settings

Tags: css, less, sublimetext3

I have

```
./style.css
./style.less (in this file i include LESSes from ./lesscss/*
./lesscss/*.less
./lesscss/modules/*.less
```

How I can set less2css?

If I set: this works if editing `style.less`. But if I edit some files from `./lesscss/` and I save it, than it crashes.

```
{
    "autoCompile": true,
    "minify": true,
    "outputDir": "./",
    "lessBaseDir": "./",
    "main_file": "style.less",
}
```

error:

```
lessc: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open .../gcm/skins/zmo/lesscss/style.less'
```

but correct path is

```
.../gcm/skins/zmo/style.less'
```

Comment: Where does your config file live in the context or your `lessBaseDir`? Sounds like you need`lessBaseDir: '../`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Project - Save Project As..
2. Edit config.sublime-project file which saving by step 1
3. Adding code in config.sublime-project

```html
{
  "folders":[{
    "path": "\/Users\/joomla178\/githubsource\/sublime-less2css-path"
  }],
  "settings":{
    "less2css":{
      "lessBaseDir": "\/Users\/joomla178\/githubsource\/sublime-less2css-path\/less",
      "outputDir": "\/Users\/joomla178\/githubsource\/sublime-less2css-path\/css",
    }
  }
}
```

4. modifing the path, lessBaseDir and outputDir by your project